# PMPI_Waitall error

Tags: c++, mpi

i've some problems with this piece of code.

```
NEIGHBOORDHOOD_FLAG = 1234;
int number_of_nodes=90;
MPI_Request neig_request[2*number_of_nodes];
MPI_Status neig_status[2*number_of_nodes];
int neig_counter=0;
int is_neighbour_send[number_of_nodes];
int is_neighbour_receive[number_of_nodes];
for(int v=2;v<number_of_nodes+2;++v){
    is_neighbour_send[v-2] = (util.check_targets(neighbours,v)==true)?1:0;
    this->communicate_neighborhood(&(is_neighbour_send[v-2]),v,&(neig_request[neig_counter]));
    ++neig_counter;
}
//ricevo la comunicazione dai nodi per sapere di chi sono vicino
for(int v=2;v<number_of_nodes+2;++v){
    this->receive_neighborhood(&(is_neighbour_receive[v-2]),v,&(neig_request[neig_counter]));
    ++neig_counter;
}

MPI_Waitall(neig_counter,neig_request,neig_status);
```

The two methods above are essentially two wrapped versions of the MPI send and receive:

```
void NodeAgent::communicate_neighborhood(int *neigh,int dest_node,MPI_Request *req){
    MPI_Class::send_message(neigh,MPI_INT,1,dest_node,NEIGHBOORDHOOD_FLAG,req);
}   

void NodeAgent::receive_neighborhood(int *is_neighbour,int node_mitt,MPI_Request *req){
   MPI_Class::receive_message(is_neighbour,MPI_INT,1,node_mitt,NEIGHBOORDHOOD_FLAG,req);
}
```

with send and receive **static** methods:

```
void MPI_Class::send_message(void *content,MPI_Datatype datatype,int length,int dest,int tag,MPI_Request *request){
   int np = MPI_Class::count();
   MPI_Isend(content, length, datatype, (dest % np), tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request);
}

void MPI_Class::receive_message(void *buffer,MPI_Datatype datatype,int length,int dest,int tag,MPI_Request *request){
   int np = MPI_Class::count();
   MPI_Irecv(buffer,length,datatype,(dest % np),tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,request);
}
```

The number of nodes is the number of processes - 2 (there are two processes that i use for others operations) and i've used the " % " in send and receive to ensure that the sender and the recipient are always in the range that i want.
The interesting thing is that this code executes properly also with large number of process (100). The problem arises when i launch the program on **two machine**s or more... 
It gives me: **Fatal error in PMPI_Waitall: See the MPI_ERROR field in MPI_Status for the error code**
I tried to print the MPI_ERROR of each status, but are all zeroes...

Can someone help me?
many thanks in advance

Edit, here the **MCVE**:

```
  #include <mpi.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  int main(int argc,char **argv){
     MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
     int my_id;
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
     int world_size;
     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
     MPI_Status * statuses = (MPI_Status *)malloc(2*world_size * sizeof(MPI_Status));
     MPI_Request * requestes = (MPI_Request *)malloc(2*world_size * sizeof(MPI_Request));
     int counter =0;
     int *tosend = (int *) malloc((world_size - 2) * sizeof(int));
     int *toreceive = (int *) malloc((world_size - 2) * sizeof(int));
     for(int i=0;i<world_size-2;++i){
        tosend[i]=0;
     }
    if(my_id>1){
     for(int i=2;i<world_size;++i){
        MPI_Isend(&tosend[i-2],1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&requestes[counter]);
        ++counter;
      }
    }
    if(my_id>1){
       for(int i=2;i<world_size;++i){
         MPI_Irecv(&(toreceive[i-2]),1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&(requestes[counter]));
         ++counter;     
       }
   }
    MPI_Waitall(counter,requestes,statuses);
    free(statuses);
    free(requestes);
    free(tosend);
    free(toreceive);
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Also this code executes correctly on a single machine. The problem arises when i launch it on 2 machines mutual authenticated (ssh). I just discovered that after the MPI_Waitall fatal error, if i try to connect via ssh from a machine to other, it ask me the password....
Why? At this point i think the problem is the communication via ssh and not the code..

Edit2: solved! it was a ssh problem that i solved in some way (i don't know how honestly, i  redid the authentication procedures ten times as long as it worked....

Comment: I suspect the issue comes from the potential asymmetry between send and receive calls. A given process always expects receiving from a process it sends to. But this remote process might not plan to send to the current process in the first place... Just check that carefully.

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly what you mean. My calls are: I send to all the ids greater than 2 and I receive from all the  ids greater than 2. Where is the asymmetry? Note that id 0 and id 1 shouldn't execute this code.. (this is only a small part of code...)

Comment: Actually, your `%np` is dangerous: it might hide a fundamental issue. Indeed, if ever it ends up truncating the `dest`, then you'll try to communicate with process id 0 which won't have initiate the corresponding send and receive calls. That's what I'm afraid of. But it's impossible to say since your code isn't a [proper mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i also tried to remove the % and the problem continues to exist...

Comment: In other, on single machine it works correctly. The error arises when i launch it on a cluster...

Comment: can you post a [MCVE] ?

Comment: of course, i also add a note that i've just discovered..